# can't add multiple condition to if in vue js2

Tags: vuejs2

i want to use v-if in vue js with multiple condition
exp

```
<div  v-for="row in formFields" class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="formGroupExampleInput">{{row.nameField}}</label>

<input  v-model="product[row.nameField]"  v-if="row.type == 'Number'&& row.typeField == 'Input'" type="number" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput"  :placeholder="row.nameField">
```

but it dosen't work 
can any one help me ?

Comment: Why to times the same condition? and add a space before the &&.. row.typeField == 'Number'&&  ... must be row.typeField == 'Number' &&

Comment: sorry i made a mistake  i try what you said but it 's not working                         - invalid expression: v-if="row.typeField == 'Number' &&  row.type='Input'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if you put a space before the AND

```
<input  v-model="product[row.nameField]"  v-if="row.type == 'Number'&& row.typeField == 'Input'" type="number" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput"  :placeholder="row.nameField">
```

correct should be

```
<input  v-model="product[row.nameField]"  v-if="row.type == 'Number' && row.typeField == 'Input'" type="number" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput"  :placeholder="row.nameField">
```